# Tomcat 7.0.52 server not extracting war file(compressed file) in webapps to uncompressed format when using export with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, tomcat7

I'm trying simple dynamic web project in eclipse(Using servlet) and I'm using tomcat 7.0.52 server. To deploy application into server I'm using right click-->export-->web-->War option in eclipse.When I export war for first time, war is created and successfully uncompressed. Then I made some modification in my servlet(compiles well) and I have exported for the second time now the war is created successfully but it is not extracting to uncompressed file.

Comment: You should first undeploy the current application, then tomcat will redeploy it by you. This means, delete the current uncompressed folder and restart tomcat.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza every time I dont want to restart the server..Is there any options to make it possible?

Comment: Yes, just right click in your Dynamic web project and select *Run / As a web application...* then it will deploy it for you w/o creating the war. Usually, you only create the war file when going to deploy it another environment outside your local env like development, qa or production.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza that I can try when I am integrating server to eclipse.. but here I am not integrating... and I think it is not eclipse problem, it is doing its export job, but server is not extracting it well.

Comment: Then you have to do it manually...

Answer (score 1):

Installing tomcat outside the c/Program Files made me resolve the same issue. I think the permission issues of creating new folders/files inside Program Files is the reason for this. So just install tomcat to a folder in C drive or D drive.

Answer (score 0):

WAR deployment are usually to deploy in another server (not local machine)

To have you war deployed automatically:

1) Make sure the file date of you WAR file is newer than the existing one 
2) In your server.xml Tomcat config file, you include in your host  `autoDeploy="true"` and `unpackWARs="true".`

```
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
```

3) In you server.xml or context.xml, make sure relaodable="true".

```
<Context docBase="myWarName" path="/myWarName" reloadable="true" />
```

4) Tomcat user has the right to read the WAR file.

If it's a development machine and you are using Eclipse, create a Dynamic Web application, create the Tomcat Server inside Eclipse and deploy you project on the server. Start the server and it should automatically stay synchronized (except for new servlets).

Comment: Step 3 is not necessary. The reloadable attribute has nothing to do with the automatic (re-)deployment of WARs.